# Can I use an embedded iframe?

Tags: testing, iframe, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a complex page structure with an iframe (#dialogFrameContent) embbed in another iframe (#migration-iframe).

I'm using `await t.switchToIframe('#dialogFrameContent')` but I have the following error :

```
The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

         | Selector('#dialogFrameContent')
```

Is this kind of structure usable with testcafe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can embed an iframe inside an iframe. You can even embed an iframe inside an iframe inside an iframe inside an iframe. However that can be a performance problem. As a result I do not recommend doing that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that embed iframe in iframe is not a good deal but I must test this kind of apps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TestCafe allows you to use embedded iframes, but you need to switch to each parent iframe.

```js
await t
    .switchToIframe('#migration-iframe')
    .switchToIframe('#dialogFrameContent');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it but it's doesn't work.

Comment: In this case I recommend you update your question with a minimal project (or a public URL) and your test code.